# Using sklearn knn imputation on a large dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, data-imputation

I have a large dataset ~ 1 million rows by 400 features and I want to impute the missing values using sklearn KNNImputer.

Trying this off the bat I hit memory problems, but I think I can solve this by chunking my dataset... I was hoping someone could confirm my method is sound and I haven't hit any gotchas.

The sklearn KNNImputer has a fit method and a transform method so I believe if I fit the imputer instance on the entire dataset, I could then in theory just go through the dataset in chunks of even, row by row, imputing all the missing values using the transform method and then reconstructing a newly imputed dataset.

I'm wondering if there's an issue with this method regarding the chunksize or is the transformation on each new row independent?

50% of the dataset rows are fully populated... would it be better in terms of computation to fit the imputer object on only this portion of the dataset?

Comment: Hi! Could you please tell me how you solved your problem? Right now I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: Accordig to the doc KNN is recommended for less than 100k rows... https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html. Did you still managed to fit the model on the whole data set ?

Comment: Generally speaking the question is why would you want to impute missing values ? Often time having a missing values is quite informative. And imputation often have more downsides than upsides.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `memmap`

```
import numpy as np
from tempfile import mkdtemp
import os.path as path
filename = path.join(mkdtemp(), 'newfile.dat') # or you could use another dat file that already constains your dataset

# supposing your data is loaded in a variable named "data"

fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=data.shape)
fp[:] = data[:]
```

You can check full documentation on [this page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html), the code above is based on the documentation.

This way you:

- only change the declaration of your data matrices, keeping you code as clean as possible
- uses numpy built-in ndarray subclass without having to explicitly manage data retrieval from the disk